# How can I remove "[{}]" from sql strings?

Tags: python, html, sqlite

For example, when I tried to get the user's username, this happens: Hello, [{'users': 'username'}]

How can I remove the rest, and get only the username?

appreciate the help!

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear
So, in order to get the username. First we need to iterate. Like this:

```
val = [{'users': 'username'}]

for values in val:
    print(values["users"])
```

So this prints the 'username' in the dictionary.